# converting an array of size (n,n,m) to (None,n,n,m)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conv-neural-network, reshape

I am trying to reshape an array of size (14,14,3) to (None, 14,14,3). I have seen that the output of each layer in convolutional neural network has shape in the format(None, n, n, m).

Consider that the name of my array is **arr**

I tried `arr[None,:,:]` but it converts it to a dimension of (1,14,14,3).

How should I do it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with tensor objects, but you cannot have an array with `None` as a shape as far as I know in numpy. There *are* scalar dtypes which have an empty tuple as the shape, but I've never seen `None`.

Comment: The output shape of convolutional neural network layer is of (None, n, n, m). Do you mean that it's not possible with numpy?

Comment: Why do you need to do this for a single example? Are you passing this to a placeholder variable?

Comment: @coldspeed When i did abc = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[None, 14, 14, 3]), then abc.shape gives me (None, 14,14,3). I want similar for my array. I don't know what means by passing in the placeholder variable though

Comment: You can do `feed_dict={abc: arr[None, ...]}` and it will be passed to the placeholder as expected. This is what you want, right? Btw, you cannot have variable dimensions in numpy, because unlike TensorFlow, evaluation is NOT lazy. Hope that makes things clear.

Comment: @coldspeed I am doing this because I wanted to use my own values from a file as input to a layer in CNN. For now it's just array so I converted it to tensor but couldnot convert it to dimension having None on it.

Comment: It seems like defining a placeholder with a variable dimension, and then reshaping your array appropriately at eval time will work. Please explain why you think it won't.

Comment: @coldspeed I tried the placeholder as you said but it complains - IndexError: index 14 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 14 . It happens when i am assigning it to feed_dict

Comment: @coldspeed I get that error only when I use feed_dict={abc: arr[None, 14,14,3]}. I then use feed_dict={abc: arr[None, ...]} and when i print feed_dict[abc].shape, it gives me 1,14,14,3 still

Comment: Is it possible that a `Tensor` with know values (derived from a `ndarray`) cannot have an unknown dimension?

Comment: I don't know about it. If that's true than my question cannot be solved, right?

Comment: May it isn't a matter of solving the question, but rather one of properly defining the question.  I don't fully understand what a `None` dimension implies (though I have some ideas).

Comment: None generalizes that the dataset has one more dimension. I want to reshape my 3D array to 4D array by introducing None because this is how the layers of convolutional neural network produces output.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape

> A TensorShape represents a possibly-partial shape specification for a Tensor. It may be one of the following:
>
> Partially-known shape: has a known number of dimensions, and an unknown size for one or more dimension. e.g. TensorShape([None, 256])

That is not possible in `numpy`.  All dimensions of a `ndarray` are known.

`arr[None,:,:]` notation adds a new size 1 dimension, `(1,14,14,3)`.  Under broadcasting rules, such a dimension may be changed to match a dimension of another array.  In that sense we often treat the `None` as a flexible dimension.

---

I haven't worked with `tensorflow` though I see a lot of questions with both tags.  `tensorflow` should have mechanisms for transfering values to and from tensors.  It knows about `numpy`, but `numpy` does not 'know' anything about `tensorflow`.

A `ndarray` is an object with known values, and its shape is used to access those values in a multidimensional way.  In contrast a `tensor` does not have values:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor

> It does not hold the values of that operation's output, but instead provides a means of computing those values

Looks like you can create a `TensorProt` from an array (and return an array from one as well):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_tensor_proto

and to make a Tensor from an array:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor

Answer (score 1):

The shape (None, 14,14,3) represent ,(batch_size,imgH,imgW,imgChannel) now imgH and imgW can be use interchangeably depends on the network and the problem. 
But the batchsize is given as "None" in the neural network because we don't want to restrict our batchsize to some specific value as our batchsize depends on a lot of factors like memory available for our model to run etc.

So lets say you have 4 images of size 14x14x3 then you can append each image into the array say L1, and now the L1 will have the shape 4x14x14x3 i.e you made a batch of 4 images and now you can feed this to your neural network.

NOTE here None will be replaced by 4 and for the whole training process it will be 4. Similarly when you feed your network only one image it assumes the batchsize of 1 and set None equal to 1 giving you the shape (1X14X14X3)